# Prove the following statement -

Tags: group-theory

Show that in an abelian group the product of two elements of finite order is itself an element of finite order.

I need some hint to start with, I am familiar with the basic

Comment: $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, so take $n=lcm(|a|,|b|)$

Comment: will this give a generalized proof ? as we are choosing a specific value for $n$

Comment: The choice of $n$ depends only on $a$ and $b$, so this is as "general" a proof as one can get!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(ab)^n = a^nb^n$, so take $n = lcm(|a|,|b|)$

Answer (score 1):

If $a$ has order $l$ and $b$ has order $m$, can you find an $n\geq 1$, in terms of $l$ and $m$, such that $a^n=b^n=e$?

Comment: yes the lcm of l and m, got it. Thanks

Comment: You don't even have to be that clever. Just let $n=lm$.

Comment: of course  !!!!  Thanks you